# How to insert a structure instance inside a structure type array in c?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, function-pointers

## What do I want to do?

I want to make an array of `struct` types and insert `struct` instances into it.

```c
{"struct Matrix matrix1", "struct Matrix matrix2"}
```

---

## What have I done till now?

I have created a function `create_struct()` that takes the necessary parameters for the `struct` and return a `struct` pointer.

```c
typedef struct
{
    size_t rows, columns;
    int *table;
} mat;

mat *create_struct(int x, int y)
{
    mat *data = (mat *)malloc(sizeof(*data));
    data->table = malloc(sizeof(int[(x * y)]));
    data->columns = y;
    data->rows = x;
    return data;
}
```

Then I created a pointer-to-object in this case `struct` and tried inserting `struct` instances with help of a for loop and the `create_struct()` function. But doing so the program crashes.

```c
int main()
{
    size_t dimensions[2][2] = {{3, 3}, {3, 2}};

    mat *matrix;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = create_struct(dimensions[i][0], dimensions[i][1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I think the main issue is with this line.

```c
matrix[i] = create_struct(dimensions[i][0], dimensions[i][1]);
```

First of all, the above will result in to compile error `a value of type "mat *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "mat"`

So to solve this I did something like this. **Which I think is completely vague.** I might be wrong.

```c
matrix[i] = *create_struct(dimensions[i][0], dimensions[i][1]);
```

---

## What do I expect from the answers

The following should be the main point of focus:

- Is it possible to do something like I'm doing?
- Is there a better way or procedure to insert `struct` instances into a `struct` types array?
- Provide information if you feel that I lack any conceptual knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. Just allocate the memory for pointers to `mat` rather than dereferencing uninitialized pointer `matrix`. Alternatively use an array of pointer to `mat`.

```
int main()
{
    size_t dimensions[2][2] = {{3, 3}, {3, 2}};

    mat** matrix = calloc(2, sizeof *matrix);
    // OR
    // mat* matrix[2];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = create_struct(dimensions[i][0], dimensions[i][1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here is the [whole code](https://katb.in/obegetapiwe), after taking the first input for matrix[1] or you can say matrix 2 the code crashes. why?

Comment: Pls try the code on your system.

Comment: @HarshitSingh, it works fine. See https://godbolt.org/z/zvG1d8ec8. The expression "OR" means that either one of line arounds is used. I'll update the answer

Comment: Bro, I didn't just blatantly copy your solution I read it first and then applied it.

Comment: I said to check the full version of the code you tested with the incomplete version, check this https://godbolt.org/z/5TGqavzf6.

Comment: @HarshitSingh, the elements of `matrix` are incorrectly dereferenced. Use `printf("%d %d\n", matrix[i]->columns, matrix[i]->rows);`. This part of your code was missing in the question. Try https://godbolt.org/z/YMrzhx3nj

Comment: what is the difference between the 2.

Comment: @HarshitSingh, `(*matrix)[i].columns` for `i=1` is the same as `matrix[0][1].columns`. However, this object does not exists, only `matrix[0][0]` is valid. And `matrix[i][0].column` is the same as `matrix[i]->columns`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244552/discussion-between-harshit-singh-and-tstanisl).